# Display website on tv-screen long-term

Tags: android, web, chromecast, monitor, television

What's the best device to use (Chromebit, chromecast , android computer,...) to display a website on a tv-screen?

So that we only need to start-up (every morning) the tv and the tv automatically goes to a certain website.

I wanted to use a chromecast but I'm not sure you can go to a website without your computer or smartphone connected to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can program a Raspberry Pie. That will do the job and a lot more.

And like Ashish said, Chrome cast casts a screen on your TV. You can have the site opened in your phone/laptop and it can be casted to your TV. But you would need to open the site in your phone in the first place. But, if you are comfortable with programming, you can get a Raspberry Pie and program it to do whatever you wanna do.

Check it [here] (https://www.raspberrypi.org/)!

Comment: Thanks, I'm comfortable with programming so we will probably go for a Raspberry

Answer (score 0):

chromecast is a device which just cast your another devices screen so you should go for a andriod lcd,led whatever yoy like

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: my pleasure @PieterDeRop